# IE hidden input value always blank

Tags: php, html, internet-explorer

I need to add a unique key to a form in a hidden input, but IE always treat the value of the hidden input as blank. All other browsers are good.

Server:

```
<input type="hidden" name="b" value="<?php echo $uniq; ?>" />
```

IE:

```
<input name="b" style="color: #ccc;" type="hidden" value=""/>
```

Chrome:

```
<input type="hidden" name="b" value="4f7b493e09fa6">
```

Comment: That is a different input field, there is no reason why PHP would produce different output for different browsers unless you are UA sniffing. How are you populating `$uniq`?

Comment: Every version... I have a new discover: "value" in the console is blank but in the "view source" is normal, and when i submit the form the value is blank.

Comment: @DaveRandom That's the same field. $uniqid=uniqid();

Comment: @DaveRandom You can help me to check it at http://accounts.dachaocai.com/register You can post a form using IE if you want to check the posted value, and if the field named b is blank the server will tell you.

Comment: @LotusH The problem is somewhere in your Javascript in the `global2.js` file, which contains the entire jQuery library and has been minified so it's quite difficult for me to find the exact problem. This may be a jQuery bug, try using the latest version.

Comment: @DaveRandom Thanks for your help :) I'll just use another method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are really having issues, just use css's `display:none`, but I agree with @DaveRandom, that is a different field.